# title based on book item

Tags: discussion, question-title

I find this title not very informative:

[How does const storage work? (Item 2, Scott Myers Effective C++)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142475/item-2-scott-myers-effective-c-question)

I [suggested](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/4568) the following title: `storage of const objects`.
The goal was to descibe the actual problem of the OP, and not some item in a book. The edit was rejected with the following comment: `The change do the title does not improve it - it removes some information that is useful when browsing.`.

Is the first title good enough? How can it be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing title is bad, and yours is better, but it could get a bit better. Titles are preferred in question form if possible. `How does const storage work?` or `Why is const better than #define?` seem like better titles to me. Also since the title of the book is in the title and not the question it would need to be added to the body in order for it to make sense, which may be the reason your edit was rejected.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I had not realized that the title of the book wasn't in the body.